# Creating integer field from string with characters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, regular-expression

I am trying to create a new attribute field in a layer that converts a string with characters into an integer.

EXAMPLE:
234' -> 234
or
234'* -> 234

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: All values start with number? And all characters always come after the numbers? What if the value is `**234'*2345-+`? @MrXsquared meant this kind of details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the numbers you want from the string are positive and integers only, then you can use an expression in the Field Calculator like `regexp_substr(  "Fieldname" , '(\\d*)' )`. Or, if there are possibly negatives and/or real numbers try this: `round(regexp_substr(  "Fieldname" , '([.-0123456789]+)' ),0)`.