# Creating integer and string fields in attribute table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, virtual-layer

I am trying to create a new attribute field `"FromNode"` in a layer that  contains string with an integer.

EXAMPLE: `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, `name4`, `...` till the end of the table.

I got the solution by doing manually in QGIS Field Calculator.

```
concat('name', "id")
```

The manual procedure is tedious due to multiple layers.

Is there a way to automatically do this using PyQGIS or even SQL query in `Virtual layer` approach?

**Attempt in PyQGIS**

Problem: It only creates empty 'String' field. I want to update the field with string `"Name"` + increment of `"integer 1"` in each row. For instance, `name1, name2, name3, ...`

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

myField = QgsField('FromNode', QVariant.String,'character', 200)
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([myField])
layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: You can search for your specific tasks: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=iterate+qgis+layers and https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#evaluating-expressions After you attempt to use both in a single script, you could let us know if you're facing any trouble.

Comment: I already search but most of solutions are based on field calculator such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387624/creating-integer-field-from-string-with-characters-in-qgis

Comment: @GermánCarrillo. Edited the question and  updated the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('FromNode', QVariant.String, '', 20)])
lyr.updateFields()
fld_idx = lyr.fields().lookupField('FromNode')
for count, f in enumerate(lyr.getFeatures()):
    lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {fld_idx: f'name{count+1}'}})
```

Edit in response to further request in comment (start count at 6000):

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('FromNode', QVariant.String, '', 20)])
lyr.updateFields()
fld_idx = lyr.fields().lookupField('FromNode')
count = 6000
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {fld_idx: f'name{count}'}})
    count += 1
```

Edit 2 in response to further subsequent request. After running the code above to add and populate the 'FromNode' field, run the code below:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

fld_list = [QgsField('baseVoltag', QVariant.String, '', 20),
            QgsField('headTermin', QVariant.String, '', 20),
            QgsField('class', QVariant.String, '', 20)]
            
lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes(fld_list)
lyr.updateFields()
fld_values = ['415V', NULL, 'EnergyConsumer']
att_map = {}
for i, fld in enumerate(fld_list):
    att_map[lyr.fields().lookupField(fld.name())] = fld_values[i]

for feat in lyr.getFeatures():
    lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feat.id(): att_map})
```

Resulting attribute table shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The above solution create new field 'FromNode' in all layers. How to restrict it to the active layer or by name of the layer?

Comment: Great. Is it possible to start the count in the field with 6000 and then incremented with 1. For example, 6001,6002,.....

Comment: @user12729159, I have updated my answer. I don't really understand though. The following remark in your question: "The manual procedure is tedious due to multiple layers" gave the impression that you wanted to perform the operation on multiple layers.

Comment: Answer updated again!

Comment: Many thanks. I am trying to create three more string fields in the same table.  Two fields "basevoltage' and "class" values are constant and third field"headTermin" with empty.It is shown in picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg59Z.png

Comment: @user12729159, see latest update!